# MacBook Pro abruptly shutdown when battery reaches ~15%

Tags: macos, battery, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

Im facing a very annoying and odd issue with my MacBook Pro.

When Im using it on battery and whenever the battery reaches around 15%, the machine simply and abruptly shutdown. This started out of nothing and is very irritating as most of the times I lost a bunch of work.

After said shutdown, the machine only boots back again when the AC cord is attached.

At first I looked around pmset configs and found nothing abnormal there that could led into this behaviour, digging thru powermanagement logs I found a very troublesome entry:

```
localhost powerd[181] <Notice>: SMC shutdown cause: 0: Battery disconnected
```

What makes not much sense to me, since the battery is non-removable.

My machine is running latest macOS Catalina patch level as:

- macOS: 10.15.4 /19E287
- Boot ROM Version: 265.0.0.0.0
- SMC Version (system): 2.37f23

Battery info (the machine is indeed not plugged right now)

- No AC;
- Not Charging;
- 31%;
- Cap=1080:
- FCC=3379;
- Design=4315;
- Time=1:26;
- -753mA;
- Cycles=178/1000;
- Location=0;

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write which MacBook Pro you have, so if it's earlier than the 2019 version, you should recalibrate your battery—if you have not already done so—with the following routine.

Catalina tends to have lot of problems with battery life (draining too quickly, draining during sleep, and so on).

After the battery is calibrated, its remaining time indicator is much more accurate. Over time, as the battery accumulates charges and discharges, its performance changes. The appropriate time between calibrations is dependent on how often you use your Mac. The process doesn't hurt anything, so it's safe to calibrate the battery a few times a year.

So these are the steps to go through:

- Start by fully charging the Mac. Don't go by the battery menu. Instead, plug in the power adapter and charge the Mac until the light ring at the charging jack or the power adapter light turns green and the on-screen battery menu indicates a full charge.
- Once the battery is fully charged, continue to run your Mac from the AC adapter for min two hours. You can use your Mac during this time as long as the power adapter is plugged in and you're running on AC power and not on battery.
- After two hours, unplug the AC power adapter from your Mac. Don't turn your Mac off. It transitions to battery power without any trouble. Continue to run the Mac from the battery until the on-screen low battery warning dialog appears. While you wait for the low battery warning (or in your case shutdown), you can continue to use your Mac (save often if working).
- Continue to use your Mac until it automatically goes to sleep because of extremely low battery power. Don't perform any critical work after you see the low battery warning, because the Mac will go to sleep before long and with no other warning. Once your Mac goes to sleep, turn it off.
- After waiting a minimum of five hours (longer is fine), connect the power adapter and fully charge your Mac. The battery is now fully calibrated, and the internal battery processor will deliver accurate battery time remaining estimates.

If you have a newer MacBook (2019+) the routine is much easier—newer MacBooks and MacBook Pros don't go through the same calibration process as its older laptops. Allow the MacBook to discharge completely and turn off. Wait for 5-6 hours, then plug in your power cable and charge the battery to 100 percent. During this time, macOS automatically calibrates the battery.

> To make accurate predictions about the remaining battery charge, the battery and its processor need to undergo a calibration routine. The calibration routine helps the processor gauge the battery's current performance and make accurate predictions about the remaining battery charge

If this does not change the situation, it may be a hardware related issue, then only an Apple dealer / service center can help you further.

Comment: it's a late 2016 MacBook Pro 13,2 TouchBar. I ended up doing a similar procedure of what suggested, but priory, I did a SMC reset, and appears it helped. I was able to completely drain the battery and got a successfully shutdown reason (-60). - 
`localhost powerd[181] <Notice>: Warning level: 3 time: -1 cap: 175
localhost powerd[181] <Notice>: SMC shutdown cause: -60: Battery fully drained`

 I'll try run at least 2 more cycles and stress the battery on this to make sure it behaves as expected. Appreciated.